# Splitting data into a per-year basis using SQL with pivots

Tags: sql, database, oracle, pivot

I'm having some trouble figuring out how construct a series of SQL statements to split some data I have into a per-year basis. There are n items which have a recorded quantity for a set of days across so many years. Here's is a a small sample layout for the main data I have.

```
   |========|==============|===========|
   | Name   | Date         | Quantity  |
   |========|==============|===========|
 1 | AAAAA  | 10-DEC-2008  | 5         |
 2 | AAAAA  | 11-DEC-2008  | 2         |
 3 | AAAAA  | 12-DEC-2008  | 0         |
 4 | AAAAA  | 09-DEC-2009  | 3         |
 5 | AAAAA  | 10-DEC-2009  | 2         |
 6 | AAAAA  | 11-DEC-2009  | 3         |
 7 | BBBBB  | 10-DEC-2008  | 5         |
 8 | BBBBB  | 11-DEC-2008  | 2         |
 9 | BBBBB  | 12-DEC-2008  | 0         |
10 | BBBBB  | 09-DEC-2009  | 3         |
11 | BBBBB  | 10-DEC-2009  | 1         |
12 | BBBBB  | 11-DEC-2009  | 0         |
   |========|==============|===========|
```

I need to convert this into a table which takes the form.

```
   |========|==============|===============|===============|
   | Name   | Date         | Quantity 2008 | Quantity 2009 |
   |========|==============|===============|===============|
 1 | AAAAA  | 09-DEC       |               | 3             |
 2 | AAAAA  | 10-DEC       | 5             | 2             |
 3 | AAAAA  | 11-DEC       | 2             | 3             |
 4 | AAAAA  | 12-DEC       | 0             |               |
 5 | BBBBB  | 09-DEC       |               | 3             |
 6 | BBBBB  | 10-DEC       | 5             | 1             |
 7 | BBBBB  | 11-DEC       | 2             | 0             |
 8 | BBBBB  | 12-DEC       | 0             |               |
   |========|==============|===============|===============|
```

It should be assumed that there are thousands of named items in the database and the start days of recording on each year will be different, E.G., 6th Dec 2010 and 5th Dec 2009.

Hope someone can help.

Comment: whenever you want to convert columns to rows or vice versa, look into pivot/unpivot (explicitly on 11g, or "techniques" that mimic an explicit function on earlier versions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case you are using **Oracle 11g**, you can pivot the table as:

```
select *
  from (    
    select name,
           to_char(theDate, 'DD-MON') as dayMonth,
           extract(year from thedate) as year,
           quantity
      from yourTable
) 
 pivot (sum(quantity) as quantity for (year) in (2008 as y2008, 2009 as y2009))
order by name, dayMonth;
```

that returns the following

```
NAME  DAYMONTH        Y2008_QUANTITY         Y2009_QUANTITY         
----- --------------- ---------------------- ---------------------- 
AAAAA 09-DEC                                 3                      
AAAAA 10-DEC          5                      2                      
AAAAA 11-DEC          2                      3                      
AAAAA 12-DEC          0                                        
BBBBB 09-DEC                                 3                      
BBBBB 10-DEC          5                      1                      
BBBBB 11-DEC          2                      0                      
BBBBB 12-DEC          0                                           

8 rows selected
```

Comment: Great answer, thank you. This is the approach I ended up taking, using the pivots.

Comment: @LewisNorton If this was the best answer, you can still mark it as such, if you wish.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do the job:

```
SELECT
    Name, FormattedDate, SUM(Quantity_2008), SUM(Quantity_2009)
FROM
(
SELECT
    Name,
    ConvertDateToDayMonthRepresentation(YourDate) as FormattedDate,
    DECODE(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM YourDate), 2008, Quantity, 0) as Quantity_2008, 
    DECODE(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM YourDate), 2009, Quantity, 0) as Quantity_2009
FROM
    YourTable
)
GROUP BY Name, FormattedDate;
```

Please note:

1. You need to add code for each year you want to have - your Query can't have dynamic columns.
2. `ConvertDateToDayMonthRepresentation` is a user defined function that should convert a date into the string representation of day and month without the year. It is trivial to create using `EXTRACT`.

Comment: Just working on your answer, Daniel. The decode/pivot method seems the way to go. Will get back to you.

Comment: This decode approach was the one which worked. Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: @RobvanWijk: My answer has only one problem: I used the column names provided by the OP. Aside from that, it is perfectly valid. I corrected this mistake - please remove your downvote.

Comment: @RobvanWijk: You are hitting the completely wrong tone here with your comments. If you really would care about the quality of my answer, you would tell me - and all other readers - what you think is the problem with my answer. BTW: I tested this answer and it obviously works, otherwise the OP wouldn't have accepted it. You need to understand that `ConvertDateToDayMonthRepresentation` is an *exemplary* name. It seems to be obvious to anyone but you. I understand your downvote as an attempt to push your answer.

Comment: I'm sorry you feel that way. My downvote is because of your answer is not tested without saying so. I should have told you that right from the start. Sorry for that. When I downvoted it, the answer contained a keyword as columnname. I also thought you were missing aggregate functions, but since the answer is edited, I may have been wrong on that one. Anyway, this isn't worth so much fuss and characters, so I removed the downvote :-)

Comment: @RobvanWijk: Thanks for removing the downvote. When downvoting, it is always a good idea to tell the answerer exactly about the problem. This way misunderstandings can easily be solved. An answer doesn't need testing if it is correct. That I used a reserved keyword prevents successful execution of the code, that is correct. However, it doesn't change anything about the value of the answer, because the OP asked about a completely different problem and realized himself that `date` is a bad column name. Missing aggregate functions never were a problem, they were there right from the start, (cont)

Comment: (cont) see edit history. Again: Not saying that an answer is tested is **no** reason for downvoting, even an obviously untested answer isn't a reason for downvoting.

Answer (score 2):

Prior to Oracle11, you can use this standard pivot trick:

```
SQL> create table mytable (name,mydate,quantity)
  2  as
  3  select 'AAAAA', date '2008-12-10', 5 from dual union all
  4  select 'AAAAA', date '2008-12-11', 2 from dual union all
  5  select 'AAAAA', date '2008-12-12', 0 from dual union all
  6  select 'AAAAA', date '2009-12-09', 3 from dual union all
  7  select 'AAAAA', date '2009-12-10', 2 from dual union all
  8  select 'AAAAA', date '2009-12-11', 3 from dual union all
  9  select 'BBBBB', date '2008-12-10', 5 from dual union all
 10  select 'BBBBB', date '2008-12-11', 2 from dual union all
 11  select 'BBBBB', date '2008-12-12', 0 from dual union all
 12  select 'BBBBB', date '2009-12-09', 3 from dual union all
 13  select 'BBBBB', date '2009-12-10', 1 from dual union all
 14  select 'BBBBB', date '2009-12-11', 0 from dual
 15  /

Table created.

SQL> select name
  2       , to_char(mydate,'dd-MON')
  3       , sum(case extract(year from mydate) when 2008 then quantity end) quantity_2008
  4       , sum(case extract(year from mydate) when 2009 then quantity end) quantity_2009
  5    from mytable
  6   group by name
  7       , to_char(mydate,'dd-MON')
  8   order by name
  9       , to_char(mydate,'dd-MON')
 10  /

NAME  TO_CHA QUANTITY_2008 QUANTITY_2009
----- ------ ------------- -------------
AAAAA 09-DEC                           3
AAAAA 10-DEC             5             2
AAAAA 11-DEC             2             3
AAAAA 12-DEC             0
BBBBB 09-DEC                           3
BBBBB 10-DEC             5             1
BBBBB 11-DEC             2             0
BBBBB 12-DEC             0

8 rows selected.
```

Regards,
Rob.